# Order by (count records with this FK)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not very good at using complicated MySQL, so I'm stuck with a somewhat complicated (but still pretty basic, I think) situation:

I have 3 tables:

- Table A has 2 records, one with ID 1, one with ID 2. They both have a
  foreign key to Table B, which is the same.
- Table B currently has only
  one record, but will have more in the future.
- Table C has multiple
  records, all with a reference to either record 1 or 2 in Table A.

What I want to achieve:
I want to select all (or some) information about Table A's records, but only for those records that reference to the record in Table B. Now here's the catch for me: I want to order the results, starting with the one which has the most records in Table C referring to it.

So:

```
    SELECT COUNT(C.*) AS NUMBER_OF_RECORDS, A.* 
    FROM `TableA` A, `TableB` B, `TableC` C
    WHERE A.bID = 1 AND C.aID = A.ID
    ORDER BY NUMBER_OF_RECORDS DESC;
```

Something like that, except that this doesn't work for `C.aID = A.ID`. I hope the above query will just make my intentions more clear.

Any help greatly appreciated!

**Better view of the situation with sample data**

Tables:

1. Department
2. Location
3. Employee

So now say, I would want to select all data of the departments in one location, ordered by the amount of employees.

Desired output:

---

departmentID, departmentName, no_of_emps
1, Sales, 14 
2, Finance, 12
3, Management, 6

Comment: You need a grouping statement, since you have aggregate function `COUNT`.

Comment: post some sample data n desired o/p ... Instead of explaining ur question in long paragraphs if u post sample data everyone can understand and help u easily...

Comment: This is going to be a bit complicated and my MySQL skills are not up to the challenge (don't have a test platform). I think you'll need to use a subquery where `TableA` is INNER JOINed to `TableB` and OUTER JOINed to `TableC` -- you'll need to GROUP BY on `TableA.ID`. Hope that gives you some direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
       COUNT(C.aID) AS NUMBER_OF_RECORDS
     , A.* 
  FROM 
       `TableA` A
    JOIN 
       `TableB` B
      ON B.ID  = A.bID 
    LEFT JOIN                       --- so you also get rows from A (and B)
       `TableC` C                   --- that have no matching rows in C
      ON C.aID = A.ID
GROUP BY
    A.ID
ORDER BY 
    NUMBER_OF_RECORDS DESC;
```

Comment: This will not work because you cannot have items in your select that are not in your group, unless they are part of an aggregation

Comment: Did exactly what I needed, with a few edits (for example, it wouldn't take COUNT(C.*), made that COUNT(C.name) :). Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want:

```
SELECT A.departmentId, A.departmentName, COALESCE(no_of_emps,0) no_of_emps
FROM Department A
INNER JOIN Location B
ON A.LocationId = B.LocationId
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT departmentId, COUNT(*) no_of_emps
            FROM Employee
            GROUP BY departmentId) C
ON A.departmentId = C.departmentId
WHERE A.LocationId = 123
ORDER BY COALESCE(no_of_emps,0) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT `D`.`departmentId`, `D`.`departmentName`, COUNT(`E`.`employeeId`) AS `no_of_emps`
FROM `Department` `D`
INNER JOIN `Location` `L` ON `D`.`departmentId` = `L`.`departmentId`
INNER JOIN `Employee` `E` ON `D`.`departmentId` = `E`.`departmentId`
WHERE `L`.`locationId` = 1
ORDER BY `no_of_emps` DESC;
```

Please replace the table and column names as per your schema.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You want to get all tuples of A ordered by the amount of tuples of C referencing to it?

```
SELECT A.* FROM A,
(SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM C WHERE C.aid = A.ID) CNT
ORDER BY CNT.cnt
```

Comment: You forgot the tie to the B table, and to include the cnt in the final select. Also, the order is DESC